# Webmidi js does not play a sound on browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web-midi

Hey I am using the webmidi js library to play midi music on click on the browser.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/webmidi

I am using a very basic example from the library. Even though it seems that the connection works I can not here anything.

```
WebMidi.enable(function (err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("WebMidi could not be enabled.", err);
  } else {
    console.log("WebMidi enabled!");
    var output =WebMidi.outputs[0];
    console.log(output);
    output.playNote(["C3", "D#3", "G3"]);
  }      
});
```

I am running it on chrome and ubuntu 14.04.

The console.log(output) returns:

```
Output_midiOutput: MIDIOutput
connection:"open"
id:"6FF5590044F4859ED50C5167BCFE9700A1798E39AA55A628E86D39011FAECD5D"
manufacturer:""
name:"Midi Through Port-0"
onmidimessage:()
onstatechange:null
state:"connected"
type:"output"
version:"ALSA library version 1.0.25"
```

Comment: If you look hard enough you can C minor problem.

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Comment: pretty sure hat was a joke

Comment: Sorry - I couldn't resist.

Comment: @PotneySwitters open your volume monitor, do you see any activity even though you can't hear anything?

Comment: @JohnVandivier no I see nothing...examples of midi.js are running fine in the same browser(project's page)...updated the description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Midi Through Port-0 is a dummy sequencer that doesn't make any sound. I assume you are running on a Linux machine - try the command *aconnect -o* to see a list of available MIDI outputs, find the device you are trying to play the MIDI notes through and select that one as your output.

Comment: aconnect -o gives:
client 14: 'Midi Through' [type=kernel]
    0 'Midi Through Port-0'

Comment: this is the same as the one chrome tries to use

Comment: It looks like you don't have a device available to play the notes. As far as I understand it, WebMidi is just for sending and receiving MIDI messages from the browser, you still need to have an output device to receive the messages.